# Mongodb Driver 2.0 find() in VB.net not working

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I am trying to practice with the C# Driver 2.0 for MongoDB. I don't know C# so I am writing the code in Visual Basic.

When I try to print out a list code won't compile. I know I have the For Each contents commented out but that's not the problem. I want to query the db for all documents in a collection and print them out to a text box.

Below is the code that isn't working. The last part is giving me trouble.

```
Private Sub btnListUsers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnListUsers.Click

    Dim ConnString As String
    ConnString = txtConnStr.Text

    Dim vDbName As String
    vDbName = txtDb.Text

    Dim vColName As String
    vColName = txtColl.Text

    Dim vClient As MongoClient

    vClient = DbConnection(ConnString, vDbName, vColName)

    Dim vDb As MongoDatabaseBase
    vDb = vClient.GetDatabase(vDbName)

    Dim vCol As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument)
    vCol = vDb.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)(vColName)

    Dim query As BsonDocument
    query = New BsonDocument("Names", txtListUsers.Text)

    For Each item As BsonDocument In vCol.Find(query).ToListAsync()
        'print a count
        'print bson document

    Next

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. I have been banging my head against the keyboard for hours.

BELOW IS THE CODE THAT WORKED FOR ME AFTER ALEX GAVE ME AN ANSWER:

```
Private Async Sub btnListUsers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnListUsers.Click

        Dim ConnString As String
        ConnString = txtConnStr.Text

        Dim vDbName As String
        vDbName = txtDb.Text

        Dim vColName As String
        vColName = txtColl.Text

        Dim vClient As MongoClient

        vClient = DbConnection(ConnString, vDbName, vColName)

        Dim vDb As MongoDatabaseBase
        vDb = vClient.GetDatabase(vDbName)

        Dim vCol As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument)
        vCol = vDb.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)(vColName)

        Dim query As BsonDocument
        query = New BsonDocument("Name", txtListUsers.Text)

        Dim myList As List(Of BsonDocument) = Await vCol.Find(query).ToListAsync()

        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For Each vItem As BsonDocument In myList

            'count
            i += 1

            'print bson document
            rtfDataDisplay.Text = rtfDataDisplay.Text & vbCrLf & "#" & i.ToString & " - " & vItem.ToString & vbCrLf

        Next

    End Sub
```

I had to add Async to the sub. I also had my key "Name" incorrect. After that things went smoothly. Woo Hoo!

Comment: You write "code won't compile" yet you don't include the error message the compiler produces in your question. Don't you think this might be helpful for people reading the question? Please [edit] your question and add this information. By the way, what is the return type of `ToListAsync()`? Is it an `IEnumerable` that a `foreach` can use to enumerate over?

Comment: I don't have the error in front of me. I am away from that computer. When I get home tonight I will add that information to the question.

Comment: With 2.0 driver all methods are async. vCol.Find(query).ToListAsync() will only return a task. You have to use await or wait on the task to get the actual list and then iterate it using for each. Alternate option is use vCol.Find(query).ForEach operation. You still have to await this taks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
For Each item As BsonDocument In vCol.Find(query).ToListAsync()
```

The call to the `ToListAsync()` method returns an awaitable `Task(Of List(Of BsonDocument))`, i.e. a promise that it will return a list that you can enumerate when it has completed fetching it. You need to `Await` it, to get to the list. As in:

```
Dim myList As List(Of BsonDocument) = Await vCol.Find(query).ToListAsync()
For Each item As BsonDocument in myList
    'print a count
    'print bson document
Next
```

An alternative construct offered by the MongoDB driver, is to use its `ForEachAsync` method, and supply it with a lambda delegate argument.

Comment: I don't think VB.net has "List<BsonDocument>" I think it is "List (of BsonDocument)"

I tried the code presented in the answer and I get the compile error of - 'Await' can only be used when contained within a method or lambda expression marked with the 'Async' modifier.

This post is edited from the original because I hit Enter by accident.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it is inline with what I was thinking.

Comment: @Trewaters yes, fixed the c#-ism for the generic list. And indeed async/await goes up the entire call chain. Then again if it didn't you would have no benefits in using asynchronous operations.

Comment: I'm away from the computer but I will look into this again tomorrow morning at the latest

Comment: Okay I had another issue that no one would have seen because I had the wrong key, but that wasn't causing a compile error. It was only returning no document :) I appreciate you help!